# classes and methods python

Tags: class, methods

Im using python 3.6 and want to create a Interval class. I am trying to do an add method that can add an integer and an intervall. So far I managed to generate a code that works for 
I=Interval(2,3) 
c=I+1   #c=[3,4]

however the opposite dosent work

I=Interval(2,3)
c=1+I #get the error message TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Interval'

my code for my class and method is as folow

class Interval:

```
def __init__(self,start=None,end=None):
        if end==None:
            end=start
        if start==None:
            start=end
        if start>end:
            raise TypeError('left value must be smaller than right value')

        self.start=start
        self.end=end
```

def **add** (self,other):

```
    if isinstance(other,int):    
        s2,e2=other,other
        s1,e1=self.start,self.end

    elif isinstance(self,int):
        s1,e1=self,self
        s2,e2=other.start,other.end


    else:
        s2,e2=other.start,other.end
        s1,e1=self.start,self.end
    return Interval(s1+s2,e1+e2)
```

if I try to change my elif in the add method to if nothing works. Does anyone know how to solve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried to run your code, but it seems to me that according to http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html you might want to implement **radd** method.

The first one works, because you are adding integer to Interval (I+1) and add method of Interval class gets called. However, in the second case, you are calling add method of integer class, which knows nothing about Interval.